# How to call a function and receive parameter in a function outside a linked list class using variables present in linked list

Tags: python, function, pointers, linked-list, function-call

I am using two python files, one file in which a class of linked list present and another file is the one in which I am importing first file so that I can use linked list I built in first file. The second file is for reverse file. I have already done reverse using iteration part, now trying to build a code for reverse using recursion and for that I am calling and passing arguments inside function but something did not work out and it is showing TypeError like this function has no arguments.

Please check it out my code followed by error

Second file

```
from code.linkedlist import *
llist=linkedlist()
llist.appendnodesatbegin(23)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(45)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(67)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(12)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(-11)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(0)
print ("Before reverse")
llist.display()
def reverseiterative():
    llist.current = llist.head
    llist.prev = None
    while (llist.current):
        llist.next = llist.current.next
        llist.current.next = llist.prev
        llist.prev = llist.current
        llist.current = llist.next
    llist.head = llist.prev
reverseiterative()
print("After the reverse of list using iterative method")
llist.display()
llist.p=llist.head
llist.prev=None
def reverserecursive(p,prev):
    next1=llist.p.next
    p.next=prev
    if llist.next1 is None:
        return
    else:
        reverserecursive(next1,p)


reverserecursive(llist.p,llist.prev)
print("After the reverse of list using recursive method")
llist.display()

first file:

class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.last_pointer=None
    def appendnodesatbegin(self,data):
        newnode=node(data)
        if(self.head==None):
            self.head=newnode
            self.last_pointer=newnode
        else:
            self.last_pointer.next=newnode
            self.last_pointer=self.last_pointer.next
    def appendnodesatend(self,data):
        newnode=node(data)
        newnode.next=self.head
        self.head=newnode
    def appendatmid(self,prev,new):
        temp=self.head
        newnode=node(new)
        while(temp):
            if(temp.data==prev):
                newnode.next=temp.next
                temp.next=newnode
            temp=temp.next
    def display(self):
        temp=self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data)
            temp=temp.next
    #def reversedisplay(self):
```

error is

```
reverseiterative(llist.p,llist.prev)
TypeError: reverseiterative() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

`reverseiterative` as defined:

```
def reverseiterative():
```

takes no argument, you are calling it with 2.

You were probably supposed to call `reverserecursive` given the arguments you passed and the argument's in the function signature:

```
def reverserecursive(p,prev):
```

Comment: thanks yes I was supposed to call reverserecursive but instead I called reverse iterative by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't take any parameters in it's deceleration:

```
reverseiterative(foo, bar):
```

This (or whatever values you wish to process) will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

```
from code.linkedlist import *
llist=linkedlist()
llist.appendnodesatbegin(23)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(45)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(67)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(12)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(-11)
llist.appendnodesatbegin(0)
print ("Before reverse")
llist.display()
def reverseiterative(self):
    self.current = self.head
    self.prev = None
    while (self.current):
        self.next = self.current.next
        self.current.next = self.prev
        self.prev = self.current
        self.current = self.next
    self.head = self.prev
llist.reverseiterative=reverseiterative
llist.reverseiterative()
print("After the reverse of list using iterative method")
llist.display()

def reverserecursive(self,p,prev):
    next=p.next
    p.next=prev
    if next is None:
        return
    else:
        self.reverserecursive(next,p)
llist.p=llist.head
llist.prev=None
llist.reverserecursive(llist.p,llist.prev)
print("After the reverse of list using recursive method")
llist.display()
```

Here is the second part to fix your issue:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.last_pointer=None
    def appendnodesatbegin(self,data):
        newnode=node(data)
        if(self.head==None):
            self.head=newnode
            self.last_pointer=newnode
        else:
            self.last_pointer.next=newnode
            self.last_pointer=self.last_pointer.next
    def appendnodesatend(self,data):
        newnode=node(data)
        newnode.next=self.head
        self.head=newnode
    def appendatmid(self,prev,new):
```